# How to make a class protected for inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I would like to do the same thing I do in Java with the `final` keyword. I tried to use the `const` keyword, but it doesn't work. How can I prevent other classes from inheriting from my class?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The keyword you are searching is "sealed".

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, thanks you are right, I added the link to it. It's sealed (to seal!). I have to agree that I do not use this keyword a lot.

Answer (score 5):

"NonInheritable" for VB.NET

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h278d2d4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In general you should mark your type with sealed keyword in case you want prevent derivation. However is some cases it is not appropriate. For example, you want to allow types from your assembly to derive from your publicly accessible type but prevent third parties from derivation.

Here few tricks which allow you to do this:

- [Preventing third-party derivation, part one](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/26/preventing-third-party-derivation-part-one.aspx)
- [Preventing third-party derivation, part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/10/06/preventing-third-party-derivation-part-two.aspx)